# SSH screen dies every now and then

Tags: ssh

I am trying to run node.js app. Every now and then I find that my app is not running & I have no idea why. I have used nodemon, forever, nohup. When I set screen, find few days later that my app is again down, I login into SSH and see that screen is dead.
When starting my app with forever I see warning saying I have not set --minUptime, --spinSleepTime and default 10000ms is used. Does that mean when my host server fails to reply in 10 seconds, my "forever" is getting terminated?

Edit: As It is my first project to host it like this, I am not sure what info to share and where to get it, as far as I know I am hosting my server at a2hosting.com, with server that has 2x2.1 ghz CPU and 3gb RAM.

Comment: No.  Spinning is when an app won't start and `forever` keeps trying to restart it in an endless loop.  If it dies in less than 10 seconds `forever` will sleep a while before trying again.  If it dies in more than 10 seconds `forever` will immediately restart it.

Comment: These type of failures are very difficult to diagnose.  Generally you try to ensure adequate logging to a file not to `screen`.  Could you edit into your question more information about the server you are running this on?  There are some issues you can face with virtual machines where processes are killed due to memory or even CPU constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a long shot.. Personally I have had problems in the past with other applications running in screen in case the application has been outputting data but the client connection has become blocked due to e.g. network problems. By default this blocks the application as well, which may trigger anomalous behaviour in the application. To stop a blocked client connection from affecting the application you can add this line to `~/.screenrc`:

```
defnonblock on
```

You will need to restart screen for this to take effect.